# does accessing the firebase firestore database dashboard will be considered as read operation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

I am now in developing phase for the project. currently the project only using one Android app as the frontend. the query from Android using limit and pagination. but the total number of documents read is way above the expected number.

I am trying to figure this out, why the number of read documents is so big even though the user is only one (me). I am scared the project will not be feasible if the number of read is so big. thats why i need to figure out the firestore read behaviour

When I accessed the firestore dashboard, and select a collection like the image below, it will show blue loading indicator and then show all documents available. currently in the event collection I have 52 documents. I access all documents in the event collection like this for several times for debugging purpose.

so whenever i tap that event collection, I assume it will be counted as 52 read operation, so the read operation will not only come from Android device but also from the dashboard ? thats why the number of reads is so big. am I right ?

if thats the case....

say if I have 100000 documents in event collection, then whenever i tap that event collection, will i perform 100000 read operation as well ? is there a way to limit this dashboard read ?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> so the read operation will not only come from the Android device but also from the dashboard? That's why the number of reads is so big. am I right?

Yes, you are right.

> say if I have 100000 documents in event collection, then whenever I tap that event collection, will I perform 100000 read operation as well?

No, you'll be charged only for the number of documents that belong to the first page. Inside the Console, there is a pagination mechanism especially implemented for that. So you'll be **not** charged for all the documents that exist in your collection.

> Is there a way to limit this dashboard read?

The limitation already exists but be aware that as much as you scroll down, you get more documents which means more read operations charged.

Comment: How many documents per page does it query?

Comment: @Manbus I don't know for sure. You can open the console and see how many reads are added to the existing ones.

Answer (score 4):

One thing to bear in mind about the Firebase console is that it reflects changes to visible documents in real time, and each one of those changes also costs you a read.  So, if you leave the console open while documents are changing, you will accumulate reads over time, even if you aren't actively using the console.  This is a common source of unexpected reads.