# Firebase firestore document reads and writes increasing very fast due to which the bandwith of firestore is increasing fast

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWCbM.png)I am new to firebase firestore I am building travel app where people visit android app check for adventure events book them . i have never used firestore its my first time , I don't know if the data modelled is correct can anybody please help me because document reads and write are increasing very high rate as i expected . here i have attached all screenshot of my code and firestore collection photo , data usage chart , document reads and write photo [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4MYk.png)

Comment: It's impossible to say without a [minimal reproduction](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but keep in mind that keeping the console open on the Firestore panel actually counts as reading the documents shown there (because... they actually need to be read to be shown there). This is a common source of confusion for developers new to Firestore.

Comment: @FrankVanPuffelen very insightful, thank you for pointing this out! How about when you open the Firestore console for the first time(i.e logging into firebase), then we can see all the documents. Does this count as a read for all the documents being displayed on screen? Or billing is counted when changes start happening(i.e red flashes for documents) white we have the console open? Thanks.

Comment: The charge is called "document read", so it charges when a document is read. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58710333/does-accessing-the-firebase-firestore-database-dashboard-will-be-considered-as-r